# csv.writer Append a csv file with new data only

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a script that is used to scrape data from a website and stores it into a spreadsheet

```
with open("c:\source\list.csv") as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    for url in row:
      r = requests.get(url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
      tables = soup.find('table', attrs={"class": "hpui-standardHrGrid-table"})
          for rows in tables.find_all('tr', {'releasetype': 'Current_Releases'})[0::1]:
        item = []
        for val in rows.find_all('td'):
          item.append(val.text.strip())
      with open('c:\output_file.csv', 'a', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow({url})
        writer.writerows(item)
```

As of right now, when this script runs, about 50 new lines are added to the bottom of the CSV file (Totally expected with the append function) but what I would like it to do is to determine if there are duplicate entries in the CSV file and skip them, and then change the mismatches.

I feel like this should be possible but I can't seem to think of a way

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't "fix" your question by replacing it with the answer to your problem. It no longer made any sense as a question, so I restored the old version. If you are confident that your own solution adds something to the answers you were given (and in this case, you shouldn't be), then create an answer to your own question explaining how you solved the problem. But leave the question be; edits are for clarifying the question, not for making it go away.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that without reading the data from the CSV file. Also to "change the mismatches", you will just have to over write them.

```
f = open('c:\output_file.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer = csv.writer(f)

for item in list_to_write_from:
    writer.writerow(item)
```

Here, you are assuming that `list_to_write_from` will contain the most current form of the data you need.

Comment: To "change the mismatches", the only sane way is to wipe out the CSV and write it out again.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.

Comment: Glargh... the issue with changed the 'a' to 'w' is that in my loop , it causes it to only write 1 line of text instead of 30... 

I will try using your if not loop, and see if that does what i need it to. 

Thank you!

Comment: That is because you are opening the file each time you want to write a single row, so it over writes whatever it had written before. To fix that, try my edited code.

Comment: I found a workaround for my issue:

I first delete the existing file if it exists using an if statement, then the rest of the code just recreates. I will post my full working code in the main post for future reference

I added:

    if os.path.isfile("c:\source\output_file.csv"):
        os.remove("c:\source\output_file.csv")

To the very top, and tested/working.

Comment: @Kevin your "workaround" is a terrible idea. Stick to the approach that this answer recommends. You'll understand why before to long.

Comment: @KevinJohnson I prefer to use "her" please :)
What did not work? You are 'appending' to a new file, which is the same as over writing everything if the file exists, or else creating a new file. Using the write mode implicitly performs this check.

Comment: @Kevin thanks for putting your solution in an answer. I still recommend you work on getting _this_ approach to work with your code. It is correct, you just have to put the pieces in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this problem as the answer provided did not work for me

I added:

```
if os.path.isfile("c:\source\output_file.csv"):
    os.remove("c:\source\output_file.csv")
```

To the top of my code, as this will check to see if that file exists, and deletes it, only to recreate it with the most up to date information later. This is a duct tape way of doing things, but it works.